# Apresentações (slidify e Rpres) com caracteres latinos (ç, ã, é...) corrompidos

Tags: r

Estou preparando slides no R, mas os caracteres latinos (ç, ã, é  etc...) ficam corrompidos quando a apresentação é compilada. Tentei tanto com o slidify como com o Rpre, mesmo problema. Alguém sabe resolver?

Edição: Se for dentro de uma mesma seção, No R studio, clicar em:

file> "save with encoding" > UTF8

isso resolve os problema na hora de visualizar. Mas surge um novo problema:

Depois de salvar, quando eu reinicio uma nova seção do RStudio e reabro o arquivo o código fonte aparece todo 'corrompido' (ex: "atenção" vira : "atenÃ§Ã£o"). Entretanto a versão compilada continua correta (aparece "atenção").

Tentei novamente usar o "save with encoding", para continuar ediatando o texto, mas aí ele corrope a visalização (versão compilada) do texto anterior.

Alguém tem idéia como resolver isso?

Systema: Windows 8.1 64bits, R version 3.1.1, RStudio 0.98.1017

Comment: se voce salvar com encoding utf8 nao funciona?

Comment: pois é, no RStudio, quando eu salvo um arquivo de Markdown  ele faz esta pergunta do encoding e quando compila fica certo. Mas quando e crio o R presentation ele não pergunta isso. Como faria para definir o encoding

Comment: quando tem algum código errado na apresentação esse erro também aparece para mim

Comment: Windows ou Linux? Acho que é problema do SO... Eu tenho esses problemas no Windows, mas não no linux.

Comment: windows, editei acima

Comment: O padrão do Windows geralmente é latin1 (iso 8859-1) tenta ressalvar com esse encoding ao invés de utf-8. Provavelmente você está salvando com utf-8 e depois abrindo em latin1 (que é o default) por isso aparecem os caracteres estranhos.

Answer (score 3):

Descobri como fazer. No R studio, clicar em:

file> "save with encoding" > UTF8

isso resolve os problema na hora de visualizar

Na questão de reabrir o arquivo numa nova seção de RStudio e conseguir vizualizar corretamente e segui adicionando novos conteúdos:

- abrir o arquivo
- file > reopen with encoding > UTF8

tudo volta a funcionar

Comment: Lucas, isso não resolve o problema ? Caso negativo favor excluir a resposta

Comment: tenta usar o reopen with encoding no RStudio

Comment: @gmsantos: Editei a pergunta para incluir a resposta acima. Ok, vou excluir

Answer (score 2):

O padrão do Windows é latin1 (iso 8859-1) e o Rpres está gerando o arquivo HTML como UTF-8.

Quando você salva o arquivo com o encoding UTF-8, então o HTML e o arquivo fonte vão estar iguais e os caracteres aparecerão corretamente.

Quando você fecha o RStudio e reabre o arquivo, como o default é latin1, mas o arquivo está como UTF-8, os caracteres irão aparecer "errados" ( "atenção" vira : "atenÃ§Ã£o"). Uma "solução" para isso é reabrir com o encoding UTF-8 (reopen with encoding) para continuar trabalhando.

Uma outra opção é fazer tudo em latin1 normalmente (no começo vai parecer que o html está "errado") e depois que você gerar o html é só mudar o charset: onde tem `<meta charset="utf-8">`  você muda para `<meta charset="latin1">`.

Aparentemente não há uma opção de falar para o Rpres qual o encoding do seu HTML. Se houvesse esta opção, bastaria especificá-la para ficar igual ao encoding do arquivo .Rpres ao invés de ir mudar diretamente no HTML.

Comment: Excelente, obrigado, Carlos. Eu na verdade estou fazendo tudo pelo point-click do RStudio (num aquivo .Rpres > botão "preview"). Não sei compilando pela linha de comando haveria como contornar isso.

Comment: você teve o mesmo problema com o Slidify, ou ele aceita Latin1 mais facilmente?

Comment: Mais um adendo (só para não abrir uma nova pergunta): tenho problemas similares de encoding com o comando View() . Há alguma solução para isso?

Comment: @LucasMation acho que para você, então, a melhor opção seria sempre fazer o reopen with encoding (depois de salvar como UTF-8). A questão do View é o mesmo "problema". O RStudio na verdade é um navegador (em HTML e javascript) e ele abre as janelas como páginas em UTF-8. Mas quando criamos nossas variáveis, elas são em latin1 (veja isso fazendo `x <- "ã"; Encoding(x)`. Daí o View não é mostrado corretamente (mas os dados estão ok). Isso ocorre também com título de help de pacotes, infelizmente. Quanto ao Slidify, tenho que testar, pois sempre usei no Mac e lá não dá problema.